# Samsung Galaxy A10 restarts automatically

Tags: reboot, android-10, samsung-one-ui

I have had my mobile for almost a year, but recently it started to restart unexpectedly. This happens most often while charging, but exceptionally it happens at other times. It only occurs to me that it causes unstable applications, but I can only guess which causes it, unless the problem is somewhere else.

Please help.

Thank you.

PS. Samsung Galaxy A10 - Android 10 (ONE UI 2.0)

Comment: Does the phone is getting hot when such reboot occur?

Comment: @Robert No, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't advise anyone. Resetting didn't help either, so the problem is on the hardware side (as I found out, probably the battery) and only complaints will solve it. Fortunately, my cell phone is still under warranty.